how to hide and unhide some widgets in flutter with bloc
There is this flutter app that I was asked to developed using bloc state management and I was also asked to use only one screen for authentication, login and registration. What happens is that all other fields should be hidden and only one field for email should be shown at the time of launching the app. When the user typed in his email address and click ok, the app should authenticate the user. That's if the email address exist, it would bring out a password field for the user to enter his password for login else if the email address doesn't exist, it will bring out other fields for user to perform a registration. Note that all these are to be done on one screen(Maybe some of those input fields should be hidden). I am a bit confused on how to achieve that and I really need help.I am not going to paste everything because of space but the few I paste should be able to explain everything that I did
class AuthController {
  final BuildContext context;
  AuthController({required this.context});


Future<void> handlePreview() async {
    final state = context.read<AuthBloc>().state;
    String email = state.email;
    if (email.isEmpty) {
      toastInfo(msg: "Please Enter Email Address");
      return;
    }
    try {
      AuthModel authModel = AuthModel();
      authModel.email = email;
      AuthRepository.preview(authModel).then((value) => {
            if (value.response!.code == 200)
              {
                //show login fields
              }
            else
              {
                //show sign up fields
              }
          });
    } catch (e) {
      toastInfo(msg: e.toString());
    }
  }


  Future<void> handleRegistration() async {
    if (context.mounted) {
      final state = context.read<SignUpBloc>().state;
      String firstName = state.firstName;
      String middleName = state.middleName;
      String email = state.email;
      String password = state.password;

      if (firstName.isEmpty) {
        toastInfo(msg: "Please Enter your First Name");
        return;
      }
      if (email.isEmpty) {
        toastInfo(msg: "Please Enter your Email Address");
        return;
      }
      if (password.isEmpty) {
        toastInfo(msg: "Please Enter your Password");
        return;
      }
      try {
        showLoaderDialog(context);
        SignUpModel signUpModel = SignUpModel();
        signUpModel.firstName = firstName;
        signUpModel.middleName = middleName;
        signUpModel.email = email;
        signUpModel.password = password;
        AuthRepository.signUp(signUpModel).then((value) => {
              if (value.response!.code == 200)
                {
                  toastInfo(msg: value.response!.message!),
                  if (context.mounted)
                    {
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                          AppRoutes.HOME, (route) => false)
                    }
                }
            });
      } catch (e) {
        toastInfo(msg: e.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  
  Future<void> handleLogin() async {
    final state = context.read<LoginBloc>().state;
    String email = state.email;
    String password = state.password;

    if (email.isEmpty) {
      toastInfo(msg: "Email Address Required");
      return;
    }
    if (password.isEmpty) {
      toastInfo(msg: "Password Required");
      return;
    }
    try {
      LoginModel loginModel = LoginModel();
      loginModel.email = email;
      loginModel.password = password;
      AuthRepository.login(loginModel).then((value) => {
            if (value.response!.code == 200)
              {
                toastInfo(msg: value.response!.message!),

                if (context.mounted)
                  {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                        AppRoutes.HOME, (route) => false)
                  }
              }
            else
              {
                toastInfo(msg: value.response!.message!)
              }
          });
    } catch (e) {
      toastInfo(msg: e.toString());
    }
  }
}

class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvents, LoginState> {
  LoginBloc() : super(LoginState()) {
    on<LoginEmailEvent>(_emailEvent);
    on<LoginPasswordEvent>(_passwordEvent);
  }

  void _emailEvent(LoginEmailEvent event, Emitter<LoginState> emit) {
    emit(state.copyWith(email: event.email));
  }

  void _passwordEvent(LoginPasswordEvent event, Emitter<LoginState> emit) {
    emit(state.copyWith(password: event.password));
  }
}

class LoginState {
  final String email;
  final String password;

  LoginState({this.email = "", this.password = ""});

  LoginState copyWith({String? email, String? password}) {
    return LoginState(
        email: email ?? this.email, password: password ?? this.password);
  }
}

abstract class LoginEvents {
  LoginEvents();
}

class LoginEmailEvent extends LoginEvents {
  final String email;
  LoginEmailEvent(this.email);
}

class LoginPasswordEvent extends LoginEvents {
  final String password;
  LoginPasswordEvent(this.password);
}

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF1F3F6),
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 100),
                //horizontal: ScreenUtil().setWidth(120)),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                    const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Login",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF4D70A6),
                            fontSize: 26,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        buildTextField("Email", "", (value) {
                          context.read<LoginBloc>().add(LoginEmailEvent(value));
                        }),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    buildTextField("Password", "password", (value) {
                      context.read<LoginBloc>().add(LoginPasswordEvent(value));
                      print(value);
                    }),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        AuthController(context: context).handleLogin();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 50,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFFF1F3F6),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  offset: Offset(10, 10),
                                  color: Color(0xFF4D70A6).withOpacity(0.2),
                                  blurRadius: 16),
                              const BoxShadow(
                                  offset: Offset(-10, -10),
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(170, 255, 255, 255),
                                  blurRadius: 10),
                            ]),
                        child: const Text(
                          "Login",
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF4D70A6), fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ));
    });
  }
}


and what is buildTextField(..)?

where is your sign up fields?

Are you trying to make the sign up screen on the same login screen? I think to make a separate screen for sign up

buildTextField is just a widget that customized TextField form, I just created it in a seperate file and call it instead of doing it in my main class @VladyslavUlianytskyi

I will add other fields for sign up but like I said earlier, the requirement is to use one screen for authentication, login and sign up. I wanted to keep the code simple that was why I removed the sign up fields @ChamalkaGunawardana

You are doing a great job maintaining the events of bloc for each case. To maintain visibility of textfields in your , you can keep boolean values for each texfield and update that on each event like
class LoginState {
final String email;
final String password;
final bool showEmail;
final bool showPassword;

LoginState({
this.email = "",
this.password = "",
this.showEmail = false,
this.showPassword = false,
});
 LoginState copyWith({
String? email,
String? password,
bool? showEmail,
bool? showPassword,
}) {
return LoginState(
  email: email ?? this.email,
  password: password ?? this.password,
  showEmail: showEmail ?? this.showEmail,
  showPassword: showPassword ?? this.showPassword,
);
}
}

and emit the values of the bool fields
 void _passwordEvent(LoginPasswordEvent event, Emitter<LoginState> emit) 
{
emit(state.copyWith(password: event.password, showEmail:true, showPassword:false));
}

And on the ui side you can wrap all you texfields with a blockbuilder and based on the boolean value you receive for each texfield put a conditional statement in visibility widget or you can use conditional rendering to show the particular texfield or not.
I hope it helps :)

Alright, I will try this out and get back to you @Kartikey Mahawar

Please is there a way that I can change the value of my state for example showPassword was initialized as false. I want a situation that if the user is trying to perform login or registration the showPassword should be change to true. Please how can I achieve that because when I tried something like state.showPassword = true, I am being told showPassword' can't be used as a setter because it's final @Kartikey Mahwar

Can I use something like this to change the state, state.showPassword ? false : true; @Kartikey Mahwar

You can initialize the showPassword with true if you want. And you have to maintain different states in bloc one should be the initial one and others that you can change into by events.
If you want to change any variable value, you should do it by events only like for the initial state maintain the showPassword as true if you want
and then change all their values by passing events to the bloc
